# ScrollView with Images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a simple app in xcode. I'd like to have a `ScrollView` with Images and every single Image is linked to a `viewController`. How can I do that?

Comment: There is plenty of tutorial out there like what you want. Just **Google** it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the class `UICollectionView` and handling the tap, pass the picture's info to the `UIViewController` you are gonna push or present on the screen.

Comment: Okay thank you that helped a little bit. So I have now a UICollectionView with Images and it is nice. Do you know how I link now the images to the respective ViewController.

Comment: Now it is the moment that you read the Apple documentation or some tutorial on the web. I can't write you the app :)